# Has the iAd request rate changed in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, iad

I have an app that uses iAds and I have noticed a major decline (50-60%) in the number of requests made per session since releasing an update built upon iOS 6.  My average session and session length has not changed, in fact the session length has increased slightly.  The structure of the app has not changed and the number of view controllers with ads has increased slightly.  My assumption was that after the update I would see an increase of the number of ad requests.

The code (logic-wise) that requests ads hasn't changed and in testing ads show up fine.

The only differences are that the new app is written in MonoTouch, and was previously an Objective-C app, and it is built on iOS 6.  I won't rule out the possibility I've done something foolish, but ads do appear fine in the App Store version.  I can't figure out what would cause some a steep drop in requests unless the iAd banner is just not requesting as frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to iAd support and got an explanation.  Simply put, in iOS 6 you absolutely need to be sharing the same iAd banner view between view controllers.

I was creating a new one in ViewDidLoad, based on some code I'd found a few years ago.  The newer iAd samples (AdSuite, I think?) show how to share a banner between view controllers, but the gist is just to create a singleton class or to create the banner view in your app delegate and use it everywhere.

My app update recently hit the store using the shared banner and I immediately saw a significant jump in iAd requests.  There were no other ad related changes that would have affected the requests, so I'm certain the shared banner view was the key.

Comment: iAdSuite (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 3):

Apple changed some things in iAd with iOS 6:

- You no longer specify an orientation, `ADBannerView` sizes to the orientation
- You can set `AutoresizingMask` to allow it to resize

It's possible they could have changed the refresh rate as well.

I wouldn't think MonoTouch would cause any problems.  We have a MonoTouch app, and it pulls the *most* money from iAd than any other ad network's banners we use.

Comment: I'm doubting it is related to MonoTouch as well.  I haven't confirmed in this case, but in most cases MonoTouch is just a layer on top of the Obj-C API, and doesn't get in the way.  I need to contact Apple because it looks more and more like they've just not tracked any requests from my updated app.  The numbers seem to point that way, at least.

Comment: Do you see a "message" that says something like "your app has been approved for ads"?  You should see this for each update.  Call Apple if you think you're not getting traffic.

Comment: Yeah, the message is there.  It's very odd.  I've had an iAd based app for a few years and everything looks normal on the iTunes connect side as well as the actual devices showing ads.  Thanks.  Will update what Apple support says.

Answer (score 0):

As Ken Pespisa says one should share one banner between viewcontrollers. Apart from the sample code AdSuite, there is a very good video at **WWDC 2011** explaining the code involved step by step:

[iAd implementation best practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=505)